# How to validate error body in Webflux/Webclient

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-test, spring-webclient, webflux

I have a handler method for an endpoint, that is this one:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> create(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

Validator validator = new CreateUserValidator();
Mono<UserDto> userDtoMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(UserDto.class);

return userDtoMono.flatMap(user ->
{
    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(user, UserDto.class.getName());
    validator.validate(user, errors);
    if (errors == null || errors.getAllErrors().isEmpty()) {
        return userService.create(user).flatMap(aa -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(fromValue(aa))).onErrorResume(this::handleException);
    } else {
        Set<String> errors1 = new HashSet<String>();
        errors.getAllErrors().forEach(message -> {
            errors1.add(message.getDefaultMessage());
        });
        return handleException(new InvalidAttributesException(errors1));
    }
});
}
private Mono<ServerResponse> handleException(Throwable exception) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();

        if (exception instanceof InvalidAttributesException) {
            InvalidAttributesException asd = (InvalidAttributesException) exception;
            asd.getErrors().forEach(error ->
                    errorResponse.addMessage(messagesService.getMessage(error)));
        } else {
            errorResponse.addMessage(messagesService.getMessage(exception.getMessage()));

        }
        logger.info("Error:" + errorResponse);
        return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(fromValue(errorResponse));
    }
```

As you can see, if the validator fails, the method return a bad request error with a ErrorResponse as a body.

I use a WebClient in order to test it. The WebClient has a filter to get the ErrorResponse in case of a error status:

```
  WebClient client = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new
            ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.newConnection()))).filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse ->
    {
        if (clientResponse.statusCode().isError()){
            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(ErrorResponse.class).flatMap(errorResponse ->
                Mono.error(new InvalidAttributesException(new HashSet<>(errorResponse.getMessages())))
            );
        }
        return Mono.just(clientResponse);
    })).baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();


Mono<ErrorResponse> response = (Mono<ErrorResponse>)  client.post().uri(thingsEndpoint(url)).accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).body(Mono.just(userDto),UserDto.class).ti
                    .exchange();

response.subscribe(as -> {
            List<String> expectedMessages = new ArrayList<>();
            expectedMessages.add("name is mandatory");
            expectedMessages.add("email is mandatory");
            assertTrue(as.getMessages().containsAll(expectedMessages));
        });
```

But it doesn't work. When I debug the test, it seems that when the exchange() method is called returns an exception before calling the endpoint. What am I doing bad?

Comment: You are returning a `Mono.error(new InvalidAttributesException(new HashSet<>(errorResponse.getMessages())))` from your error handler, not an `ErrorResponse`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Toerktumlare . How can I change that, because I have to return a ClientResponse if I don't return an error. And if a return an error, the error needs to contain a Throwable

Comment: when something returns a `Mono.error()` you can use one of the onError operators to decide how you want to handle the reactive flow if an error is passed along. Depending on how you want to handle the error you can (if an error comes along) instead return another value, another publisher, just drop the value, etc. You can read about how to handle errors here https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_error_handling_operators and then decide how you want to solve it.